# How to build a site with a map that shows where people offer and need help?

Tags: posts, login, forms, google-maps

I'm trying to build a site where people can ask and offer help to each other. The idea is that people could publish "help needed" and "help offered" posts by filling in a simple form (with address data etc.). The posts would then be displayed on Google maps. This way it would be easy to find people that are in need of help as well as those that are available to help.

I'm novice with WP, so I'd need some tips, what would be the best tools to use to do the following:
- Create the forms (one for help requests, one for help offers)
- Show the filled in forms on Google maps?
- Create sing-in for the service (I want to have people sign-in before they are able to post. This is to reduce misconduct.)

I'm trying to set up this service to support those that need help because of corona outbreak.

Thanks, Juhana

Comment: This is a really broad and general question and to answer it properly someone would almost have to basically plan out the entire project for you.  In earnest you should probably ask more specific questions that can be answered with definitive answers rather than something this general which essentially hinges on a lot of opinion and subjectivity.

Comment: Thanks Tony for your comment. I've now changed the question to be more specific. It would be great if someone could suggest good tools to use. Then I'll try to figure out, how to apply them on my own.